# My code is failing for two specific input tests. "No overflow" and "Big integers overflow"

Tags: java, error-handling, overflow

Part 1
Given 4 integers, output their product and their average, using integer arithmetic.

Ex: If the input is:

8 10 5 4
the output is:

1600 6
Note: Integer division discards the fraction. Hence the average of 8 10 5 4 is output as 6, not 6.75.

Note: The test cases include four very large input values whose product results in overflow. You do not need to do anything special, but just observe that the output does not represent the correct product (in fact, four positive numbers yield a negative output; wow).

Your program will fail the last test cases (which is expected) until you complete part 2 below. Leave these statements in but also add the statement(s) for part 2.

Part 2
Also output the product and average, using floating-point arithmetic.

Output each floating-point value with three digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
System.out.printf("%.3f", yourValue);

Ex: If the input is 8 10 5 4, the output is:

1600 6
1600.000 6.750
Note that fractions aren't discarded, and that overflow does not occur for the test case with large values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgrammingAssignment1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);


    int int1;
    int int2;
    int int3;
    int int4;

    int1 = scnr.nextInt();
    int2 = scnr.nextInt();
    int3 = scnr.nextInt();
    int4 = scnr.nextInt();

//pt 1
    double product = ((double) int1) * int2 * int3 * int4;
    double average =  (int1+int2+int3+int4)/4.0;

//pt 2
        int result1 = (int) average;
        int result2 = (int) product;

        System.out.printf("%d %d\n",result2,result1);
        System.out.printf("%.3f %.3f\n",product,average);
    }
}
```

Here is my code. It is failing for these tests specifically. Otherwise it runs fine.
Output differs. See highlights below.
Input
100000 200000 300000 500000
Your output
2147483647 275000
3000000000000000000000.000 275000.000
Expected output
-1679818752 275000
3000000000000000000000.000 275000.000

and

Output differs. See highlights below.
Special character legend
Input
100000 200000 300000 500000
Your output starts with
2147483647 275000
3000000000000000000000.000 275000.000
Expected output starts with
-1679818752 275000

I have tried manipulating the variable types. But with no luck

Comment: The exercise says specifically: "using *integer* arithmetic"

Comment: For the first part, you're supposed to use integer arithmetic.  For the second part, you're supposed to recalculate everything using floating point arithmetic.  In other words, you're not supposed to just recast the results from the first part, which is what you're trying to do.

Comment: so what do you mean by that? If I convert them all to ints it would be limited by the size an int can be and in turn not give me the correct answer of: 3000000000000000000000.000

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point.  If you use integer arithmetic, the product turns out to be -1679818752.  It's not numerically correct, of course, but the exercise is to demonstrate that integer arithmetic goes bad when numbers get big enough.  But because you're using floating point arithmetic to find the product, and converting the result to an `int` afterwards, you're getting 2147483647, for no other reason than that's the largest possible `int`.  This result is also numerically incorrect, of course, but it's also different from the result that the test is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using integer arithmetic, you are doing `double` arithmetic.

The problem with any number stored in a computer is that, unless you sign up to have the memory taken by it grow potentially to infinite sizes (and we haven't yet invented computers with infinite memory, so that's a problem), you're stuck having to store them in a fixed 'size'. `int` is 32-bits, `double` is 64-bits. In any case, 32 bits worth of data can only store at most 2 to the 32th power different values. doubles, given that they are 64-bit, can store at most `2^64` different unique values. For the same reason 1 plus 1 is 2 - fundamental mathematical property.

For int/long, the chosen values are all integers 'near 0', i.e. `2^31-1` on the plus side and `-2^31` on the negative side are the 'largest' numbers that an `int` can store.

If you go 'past' the edges, the numbers wrap around. That's how `int` / `long` 'solve' the problem when you try to do math that needs more bits than you have.

For `double`, instead, certain specific numbers on the number line are 'blessed' to be representable, and any other result is rounded to the nearest blessed number. As you move away from 0 (i.e. ever larger numbers), there are fewer and fewer blessed numbers. Around 2^52, the distance is more than 1 between any 2 blessed numbers, even. *This does mean that `double` can represent really, really large numbers*. Just, with a ton of error (as I said, double math silently rounds to the nearest blessed number. If the gaps between any 2 blessed numbers are large, and they are for large numbers, all that rounding adds up to lots of error). That's how `double` solves the problem when you go beyond what its bits reasonably let you do: Egregious amounts of rounding, and eventually, you get a number that is called `NaN` (not a number) if you go far enough.

So, for `double`, the result is off with increasing levels of error, or even `NaN`. It doesn't, ever, 'overflow' (flip around to the other end of the number line).

You're doing double math, hence why you aren't witnessing the 'overflow' kind of mathematical incorrectness. You're observing the rounding version.

Use all integral math as the exercise asks you to do. To get an average:

```
int product = int1 * int2 * int3 * int4;
int average =  (int1+int2+int3+int4)/4;
```

Yes, the average is now 'wrong', but the problem **explicitly says this is the desired result**.

Comment: The average is not numerically wrong in this case, because all the inputs are multiples of 4, and the sum is within range for an `int`.  It's the product that's numerically wrong, but OP has managed to get a different numerically wrong result from the one that the test was expecting.